# Decode constructor arguments of deployed Smart Contract

Tags: evm, abi, binance-smart-chain

I need to know which parameters has been used to init the following smart contract: https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x9Ac64Cc6e4415144C455BD8E4837Fea55603e5c3#code

From the page, I can only see it has been init with 2 arguments, yet they are encoded.
From the source code I can guess they are 2 addresses, but is there a way to decode them?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave the answer =) they are 2 address, the first one is 0xb7926c0430afb07aa7defde6da862ae0bde767bc, for example. The issue is that addresses have 20 bytes, and the parameters have 32bytes. That is why they are encoded as 000000000000000000000000b7926c0430afb07aa7defde6da862ae0bde767bc. Just pickup the last 20 bytes (40 digits).

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the "Constructor Arguments" section in the page you linked?
There you can see the values too (they are padded to 32 bytes (256 bits)) and simply ignore the first zeros since an `address` is 20 bytes).

However, even for not verified contracts, if you know che constructor signature (in this case `address,address`, without spaces) you can always recover the parameter values.
If you need this programmatically you can use [`ether.js`'s `AbiCoder`](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/abi/coder/) object. Otherwise there are many tools online like [this](https://adibas03.github.io/online-ethereum-abi-encoder-decoder/).

Comment: Yes I saw the Constructo Argumetns section but I thought values were encoded... Thank you for the second part of the answer too!